# Node.js: Asynchronous Callback Execution. Is this Zalgo?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Executing the below using **node - 6.0.**

```
function A(callback) {
  console.log('A');
  callback();
}

function B() {
  console.log('B')
}

function C() {
  console.log('C');
}

A(C);
B();


// Result is A,C,B i expected that A, B, C
```

But changing the above example to use process.nextTick() prints A, B, C

```
function A(callback) {
  console.log('A');
  process.nextTick(() => {
    callback();
  });
}

function B() {
  console.log('B')
}

function C() {
  console.log('C');
}

A(C);
B();
```

Is this what we call as `zalgo` ? Can anyone provide me a realtime example of this, which will cause major breakdown ?

Comment: Can you explain _why_ you expected `A,B,C`?

Comment: I thought the callback of A(B) will be deffered, meanwhile B() will get executed

Comment: Deferred through what mechanism?  `callback` could just have easily be named `andNowCallThisFunctionImmediately` - it's just a variable name

Comment: @Sathish In `A(C)`, *`C`* is the callback that might be deferred

Comment: Callback isn't performing any input / output. Why would it be deferred?

Comment: Yes, this is what we call releasing zalgo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me explain how the code works - see the comments in the code that I added:

```
// first you define function A and nothing happens:
function A(callback) {
  console.log('A');
  callback();
}

// then you define function B and nothing happens:    
function B() {
  console.log('B')
}

// then you define function C and nothing happens:
function C() {
  console.log('C');
}

// now you call function A with argument C:
A(C);
// when A runs it prints 'A' and calls C before it returns
// now the C runs, prints C and returns - back to A
// A now has nothing more to do and returns

// Now the execution continues and B can be run:
B();
// B runs and prints 'B'
```

This is exactly the same as it would be in any language like Java, C etc.

Now, the second example:

```
// first you define function A and nothing happens:
function A(callback) {
  console.log('A');
  process.nextTick(() => {
    callback();
  });
}

// then you define function B and nothing happens:
function B() {
  console.log('B')
}

// then you define function C and nothing happens:
function C() {
  console.log('C');
}

// Then you run A with C passed as an argument:
A(C);
// A prints 'A' and schedules running an anonymous function:
// () => { callback(); }
// on the next tick of the event loop, before I/O events are handled
// but after the current code stack is unrolled
// then it returns
// And then B is run:
B();
// B prints 'B' and returns
// Now nothing else is left to do so the next tick of the event loop starts
// There's one function to run, scheduled earlier so it runs.
// This function runs the `callback()` which was `C`
// so C starts, prints 'C' and returns
// The anonymous function has nothing else to do and returns
// There is no more things on the event loop so the program exits
```

### Update

Thanks to Bergi for explaining what is Zalgo in his answer. Now I better understand your concerns.

> Is this what we call as zalgo ? Can anyone provide me a realtime example of this, which will cause major breakdown ?

I've seen a lot of code like this:

```
function x(argument, callback) {
    if (!argument) {
        return callback(new Error('Bad argument'));
    }
    runSomeAsyncFunction(argument, (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
            return callback(new Error('Error in async function'));
        }
        callback({data: result});
    });
}
```

Now, the callback can be either run immediately before `x()` returns if there are bad arguments, or after the `x()` returns otherwise. This code is very common. For testing the arguments one could argue that it should throw an exception but let's ignore that for a moment, there may be some better examples of operational errors that are known immediately - this is just a simple example.

Now, if it was written like this:

```
function x(argument, callback) {
    if (!argument) {
        return process.nextTick(callback, new Error('Bad argument'));
    }
    runSomeAsyncFunction(argument, (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
            return callback(new Error('Error in async function'));
        }
        callback({data: result});
    });
}
```

it would be guaranteed that the callback will never be invoked before `x()` returns.

Now, if that can cause a "major breakdown" depends entirely on how it is used. If you run something like this:

```
let a;
x('arg', (err, result) => {
    // assume that 'a' has a value
    console.log(a.value);
});
// assign a value to 'a' here:
a = {value: 10};
```

then it will sometimes crash with the version of `x()` without `process.nextTick` and will never crash with the version of `x()` with `process.nextTick()`.

Answer (score 3):

No, neither of these is zalgo. Your first `A` function always calls its callback synchronously, and should be documented as such. Your second `A` function always calls its callback asynchronously, and should be documented as such. Nothing is wrong with that, we use thousands of these every day. The outputs `A C B` and `A B C` are *deterministic*.

[Zalgo](http://blog.izs.me/post/59142742143/designing-apis-for-asynchrony) refers to the *uncertainty* whether a callback is asynchronous or not.

```
function A(callback) {
  console.log('A');
  if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
    callback();
  } else {
    process.nextTick(callback);
  }
}
```

The output of the invocation `A(C); B();` would be totally unpredictable.

Comment: Thanks for explaining what is Zalgo (I haven't seen that term before) so I could update my answer with hopefully better explanation than what I posted before.